# Querying a list to find the count of an ID and merge the contents of two similar IDs

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a generic C# list `List<object> Results` which has several fields with several rows of data in it as follows

```
List<object> Results
```

Data:

```
TrdID    Date       Price Seller Buyer  Side
1000     7/23/2015   1     ABC    NULL   2 
1000     7/23/2015   1     NULL   XYZ    1
1002     7/22/2015   1.5   NULL   ABC    1
1002     8/22/2015   1.5   NULL   ABC    1
1002     7/22/2015   1.5   XYZ    NULL   2
1002     8/22/2015   1.5   XYZ    NULL   2
1010     8/23/2015   2     ACB    NULL   2 
1010     8/23/2015   2     NULL   PQR    1
```

The above list has records whose IDs are repeated and I want to merge records whose `IDs` are repeated twice. And the two records with same `IDs` will have same values except `Seller` and `Buyer` where `Seller` is `NULL` when `Side=1` and `Buyer` is NULL when Side=2  and merge them into a single record by replacing the NULL values with its subsequent other Side and the resultant list will be as follows

**Expected Results**

```
TrdID    Date       Price Seller Buyer  
1000     7/23/2015   1     ABC    XYZ  
1010     8/23/2015   2     ACB   PQR
```

As you can see from the above results that `IDs 1000 and 1010` are repeated twice, so it merged each of their `Seller` and `Buyer` Values and `ID 1002` is discarded as their `Count` is not 2

May I know a way to solve this?

Comment: What is the type inside your List?

Comment: What is Count (in your last sentence) ?

Comment: Count is the number of times a particular ID is repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your objects are in a class matching something like this:

```
public class Result
{
    public int TrdID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Seller { get; set; }
    public string Buyer { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can query your list by grouping by the `TrdID` value:

```
var groupedResults = Results
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.TrdID, r.Date, r.Price })
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 2)
    .Select(g => new Result
    {
        TrdID = g.Key.TrdID,
        Date = g.Key.Date,
        Price = g.Key.Price,
        Seller = g.First(x => x.Seller != null).Seller,
        Buyer = g.First(x => x.Buyer != null).Buyer
    });
```

Note: You will need to make your `Results` variable a `List<Result>` for this to work correctly, or use `Results.Cast<Result>()` first.

Comment: Little nitpick: using `FirstOrDefault` is pointless in this case since it doesn't prevent you from a `NullReferenceException` is there is no `Seller`/`Buyer` which is not null. It's a bad deal, you are changing a meaningful exception(`InvalidOperationException`,  
"Sequence contains no matching element") with another less meaningful.

Comment: 'g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Seller != null).Seller' is not logical. You may expect the group to have 1 entry with a Seller that is not null. If so, you should use 'First' rather than 'FirstOrDefault'. If you do not want to make that assumption, you need to set the Seller property to null in the case when none of the records in the group have a defined Seller.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good spot, doesn't cause a problem but it's better without `OrDefault`

Comment: @HashPsi That's a much more complicated way of saying exactly what Time just said!

Comment: @DavidG If you read the comment carefully, you will see that it makes a slightly different point.

Comment: @HashPsi: i don't understand the difference either. You additionally say that he could "set the Seller property to null in the case when none of the records in the group have a defined Seller" which is corect but not an argument to use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`. I will show an approach which handles the case that there is no non-null in my answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The comment is really about the expected contract for the Result, rather than the technical aspects of writing the query. Is it better to get a failure when the query is run (e.g., if there is no Seller defined for either of the 2 members in the group) or further down the line in the application? For that matter, is it always true that exactly 2 entries are expected? The right approach may be to reconsider how this data is generated and extract it in a different way.

Comment: @DavidG.. I have my Results variable to List<Result> as you said. But, for some reasons, it gave me `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestCME.Result>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestCME.Result>'`

Comment: @Dev Try using `ToList()` then

Comment: @DavidG. Thank you, it worked fine but I think I have some other issue. Anyways I will open a new question for that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy` and other LINQ methods:

```
Results = Result.GroupBy(x => new { x.TrdID, x.Date, x.Price })
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 2)
    .Select(g => new object 
    {
          TrdID  = g.Key.TrdID,
          Date   = g.Key.Date,     
          Price  = g.Key.Price,
          Seller = g.First(x => x.Seller != null).Seller,
          Buyer  = g.First(x => x.Buyer  != null).Buyer 
    })
    .ToList();
```

This presumes that there is always a `Seller` that is not null and also that there is always a `Buyer` that is not null. If that's not the case you get a meaningful `InvalidOperationException`: "Sequence contains no matching element".

So if that's possible you could assign `null` instead of using the properties:

```
....
Seller = g.Where(x => x.Seller != null)
          .Select(x => x.Seller)
          .FirstOrDefault(),
Buyer  = g.Where(x => x.Buyer != null)
          .Select(x => x.Buyer)
          .FirstOrDefault(),
```

Comment: This won't work if OP doesn't change his list from `List<object> Results`

Comment: @DavidG: i don't undestand. It won't work if he doesn't change, double negation, so actually  it does work?

Comment: Haha OK, dodgy grammar aside, this doesn't work in it's current form :)

Comment: @DavidG: Why, what have i missed?

Comment: The source (i.e. `Result`) is a `List<object>`, which means you can't do `x.TrdID`. Sorry for bleating on about it, I'm just a pedant!

Comment: @DavidG. you are right. should I change my `List` then?

Comment: @Dev That's what I suggested in my answer :)

Comment: @DavidG: i have presumed that is just another term for `List<MyCustomObject>`. Many call it `object` if they actually mean their classes.

Comment: @Dev: instead of using a `List<Object>` you should use a `List<MyObject>`. Replace `MyObject` with the actual name of your class.

Comment: @TimSchmelter. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
(from r in Results
group r by TrdID into g
where g.Count() == 2
let g1 = g.First()
let g2 = g.Last()
select new {
    TrdId = g.Key,
    Date = g1.Date,
    Price = g1.Price,
    Seller = g1.Seller ?? g2.Seller,
    Buyer = g1.Buyer ?? g2.Buyer
})
```

The 'Result' list will need to be typed such that the fields 'TrdId', 'Date', etc. are available in the query.

Comment: This is assuming the list will be in a particular order so might not work. Also, it will error as the source is a list of `object`.

Comment: @DavidG Yes on the typing part of the comment. The Result should be typed properly. No on the order comment based on the fact that exactly 2 entries are expected with identical TrdId and that the fields other that Seller and Buyer are expected to be the same for both entries.